# UWP Create a content dialog with one big button

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create a content dialog with only one button in the center

I've trying to change the style for the content dialog using style code but nothing changed iI Still have two button and if i use only one the button keeps on the left

Here's my code

```
    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog -->
<Style TargetType="ContentDialog">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentDialog">
                <Border x:Name="Container">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderWidth}"
                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
                MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" >
                            <Grid x:Name="DialogSpace" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    ZoomMode="Disabled"
                    Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}"
                    IsTabStop="False">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                    Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                    FontSize="20"
                    FontFamily="XamlAutoFontFamily"
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    MaxHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMaxHeight}" >
                                            <ContentControl.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                    <ContentPresenter
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          MaxLines="2"
                          TextWrapping="Wrap"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ContentControl.Template>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"
                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                    Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Grid x:Name="CommandSpace" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border x:Name="Button1Host"
                  Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostMargin}"
                  MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}"
                  MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMaxWidth}"
                  Height="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonHeight}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have change the style and I have only one button call Button1Host but when i create a content dialog nothing changed I've tryed to copy that code to my content dialog xaml using `<page.Resoures>` but I got the same value

Hope you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `CommandSpace` Grid and set the its first column width to `0`.

```
<Grid x:Name="CommandSpace"
      Grid.Row="1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Button1Host"
            Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostMargin}"
            MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}"
            MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinHeight}" />
    <Border x:Name="Button2Host"
            Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton2HostMargin}"
            MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}"
            MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinHeight}"
            Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nothing changed any ideas :/

Comment: Do you have your style in App.Resources? Also, are you using the primary button?

Comment: I'm using the primary button and I have tryied to use the secondary and nothing changed am using App.Resources yes !

Comment: Is there's any way to clear command space and create another button on a grid :/

Comment: Are you sure you have `Width="0"` in your style? What's your windows 10 target version and min version?

Comment: What if you change the Width from `0` to `20`, and make sure you remove any `MaxWidth` on the `Border` (i.e. `Button2Host`).

Comment: I forgot to change the min width so I fix it now thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something with the content template and not use the primary or secondary buttons. Have a look at the below code:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="contentD">
        <ContentDialog.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Pink">
                    <Button Content="My Lonely Button" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentDialog.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentDialog>
```

Comment: I want my button to show on the button in a full screen in grid that's not going to happen :/

Comment: Why are you using the contentDialog then? If you see when you resize the window of your app, you'll notice the content dialog switches states.

Comment: I don't want to use a page for viewing what's new in my update i think it will be more easy to view and close in content :/

Comment: what about a `usercontrol` instead?

Comment: of using a usercontrol to show a pop up kinda thing on the View without doing a page navigation?